# Quanteda warning: number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2030)

Tags: r, quanteda

Trying to parse over 7000 txt files using the `readtext library` (that ships with the `quanteda library`) in `R`, I got the following warning.

> Warning message: In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :   number of
>   columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2030)

How can I figure out which txt file(s) cause(s) the warning?

Using the verbose-option does not show were the warning occurs. For your information, trying to parse two files I get the following information (b2w if I only parse 1 doc at a time, the warning is not shown).

> Reading texts from
>   /Users/OS/surfdrive/Competenties/Data-step-1/BinnenlandsBestuur/1982/9-12/Office
>   Lens 20170308-102311.jpg.txtReading texts from
>   /Users/OS/surfdrive/Competenties/Data-step-1/BinnenlandsBestuur/1983/Office
>   Lens 20170308-103518.jpg.txt, using glob pattern ... reading (txt)
>   file: Office Lens 20170308-102311.jpg.txt , using glob pattern ...
>   reading (txt) file: Office Lens 20170308-103518.jpg.txt read 2
>   documents. Warning messages: 1: In (function (..., deparse.level = 1) 
>   :   number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length
>   (arg 2) 2: In if (verbosity == 2 & nchar(msg) > 70) pad <-
>   paste0("\n", pad) :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used

```
Session info
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/C/C/C/C/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tm.plugin.webmining_1.3 XML_3.98-1.7            readtext_0.50           RoogleVision_0.0.1.1   
 [5] outliers_0.14           stringdist_0.9.4.4      ltm_1.0-0               polycor_0.7-9          
 [9] msm_1.6.4               MASS_7.3-47             psych_1.7.5             WriteXLS_4.0.0         
[13] plyr_1.8.4              metafor_2.0-0           Matrix_1.2-9            metaSEM_0.9.14         
[17] OpenMx_2.7.12           xlsx_0.5.7              xlsxjars_0.6.1          rJava_0.9-8            
[21] readxl_1.0.0            quanteda_0.9.9-65       koRpus.lang.nl_0.01-3   koRpus_0.11-1          
[25] sylly_0.1-1             jsonlite_1.5            httr_1.2.1             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] sylly.ru_0.1-1      splines_3.4.0       ellipse_0.3-8       RcppParallel_4.3.20 shiny_1.0.3        
 [6] sylly.it_0.1-1      expm_0.999-2        sylly.es_0.1-1      cellranger_1.1.0    slam_0.1-40        
[11] yaml_2.1.14         backports_1.1.0     lattice_0.20-35     digest_0.6.12       googleAuthR_0.5.1  
[16] colorspace_1.3-2    htmltools_0.3.6     httpuv_1.3.3        tm_0.7-1            devtools_1.13.2    
[21] xtable_1.8-2        mvtnorm_1.0-6       scales_0.4.1        tibble_1.3.3        openssl_0.9.6      
[26] ggplot2_2.2.1       withr_1.0.2         lazyeval_0.2.0      NLP_0.1-10          mnormt_1.5-5       
[31] RJSONIO_1.3-0       survival_2.41-3     magrittr_1.5        mime_0.5            memoise_1.1.0      
[36] evaluate_0.10       boilerpipeR_1.3     nlme_3.1-131        foreign_0.8-67      rsconnect_0.8      
[41] tools_3.4.0         data.table_1.10.4   stringr_1.2.0       munsell_0.4.3       compiler_3.4.0     
[46] rlang_0.1.1         grid_3.4.0          RCurl_1.95-4.8      bitops_1.0-6        rmarkdown_1.5      
[51] gtable_0.2.0        curl_2.6            R6_2.2.2            sylly.en_0.1-1      knitr_1.16         
[56] fastmatch_1.1-0     sylly.fr_0.1-1      rprojroot_1.2       stringi_1.1.5       parallel_3.4.0     
[61] sylly.de_0.1-1      Rcpp_0.12.11
```

Thank you,
Peter

PS. If this info is insufficient, I'll post a reproducible example on the github page.

Comment: Try rerunning it with `readtext("yourfiles", verbosity = 3)` - this ought to identify the offending file. Otherwise please post a reproducible example at https://github.com/kbenoit/readtext/issues, along with your `sessionInfo()` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr` to look for columns that don't match what you want.

First let's create some demo data with one file that has different names from the other three...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
old_wd <- getwd()
setwd(tempdir())

demo_data <- tibble(x = rnorm(327),
                    y = rnorm(327),
                    z = rnorm(327))

write_csv(demo_data, "demo1.csv")
write_csv(demo_data, "demo2.csv")
write_csv(demo_data, "demo3.csv")

bad_data <-
  tibble(
    x = rnorm(327),
    y = rnorm(327),
    z = rnorm(327),
    extra_column = rnorm(327)
  )

write_csv(bad_data, "demo4.csv")
```

Now define what the column names should be. For this example, the correct names are `x`, `y`, and `z`,

```
correct_names <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

This function will read a csv and check if all of the names match the column names in `correct_names`.

```
get_csv_names <- function(path){
  c(path, all(names(read_csv(path)) == correct_names))
}
```

I'm assuming that you want to process all of the csv files in your working directory. Otherwise you'll want to change the value of `files` from what I have below...

```
files <- list.files() %>% 
  tbl_df() %>% 
  filter(str_detect(value, ".csv")) %>% 
  pull()
```

Now it's just a matter of mapping `files` to the function `get_csv_names`. Notice how demo4.csv has a value of `FALSE`, which means that its column names do not match what you specified in `correct_names`...

```
map(files, get_csv_names)

# [[1]]
# [1] "demo1.csv" "TRUE"     
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "demo2.csv" "TRUE"     
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "demo3.csv" "TRUE"     
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "demo4.csv" "FALSE"
```

Since we changed the working directory at the beginning, it's a good idea to reset it at the end.

```
setwd(old_wd)
```

Comment: Let me know if your .txt files are not comma separated. I'll edit my answer to match the file types.